# BIGNUM in two's complement representation

Tags: objective-c, c, openssl, bit-representation

I have [BIGNUM](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/bn.html) structure from what contains really big positive integer. I'm converting this BIGNUM to array of bytes using [BN_bn2bin](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BN_bn2bin.html) function:

```
BIGNUM *bigInteger = ...
BN_bn2bin(bigInteger, bigIntegerBytes);
```

I noticed that bigIntegerBytes is in unsigned value representation. I would like to covert this integer from unsinged value representation to [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation. Can you tell me please how to do that?

PS. I'm using objective-c so maybe there is any way to do that using NSData.